# In python 3.6, how to filter output of help built-in function using wildcards from interactive prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wildcard

I realize this isn't correct syntax.  But, Here's what I want to do:

```
>>> import MyLib.MyMod

>>> help("MyLib.MyMod.DoXyz*")
```

Is there a way to filter the output of the help command such that I only get Functions starting with string "DoXyz"?

Also, Is there a way to put output of Help command in alphabetical order at the same time?

Comment: I think you'd have to filter `dir(MyLib.MyMod)` yourself.

Comment: There's way to capture the output of `help`. What you can do is temporarily redirect stdout to a file. Call `help`, and then open the file and use regex to parse. ...Or use `dir`, yeah. That's better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create something similar after reading some ideas from COLDSPEED.

```
def help2(mpath, filter=None, mode=0):
    """Search help with filter.  Example: help2(MyMod, 'DoXyz*')"""

    if not filter:
        sg = True

    elif not mode:
        r1 = "^" + filter
        r1.replace('*',      '\u0001')
        r1.replace('\u0001', '.*')

    else:
        r1 = filter

    for x in sorted(dir(mpath)):
        if not x.startswith('_'):
            if filter:
                sg = re.search(r1, x, re.IGNORECASE)
            if sg:
                e2 = getattr(mpath, x)
                f  = x + "():"
                d  = e2.__doc__
                if d: 
                    L  = d.splitlines()[0]
                else:
                    L  = "(none)"
                print("%-30s %s" % (f, L))
```